# Firestore Listener to update Object in different View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I need help implementing a Firestore Manager Class.
For certain data, I believe that this is a better way than repeatedly detaching the listener and reattaching in multiple ViewControllers.

Example.
I am currently retrieving an array of `jobs` from ViewController1 (VC1) using the below code.

```
func fsJobColl() {

    self.jobCollectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Job")
    self.jobListener = self.jobCollectionRef
        .whereField("jobUsers", arrayContains: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")
        .addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                debugPrint("Error fetching docs: \(err)")
            } else {
                self.jobs.removeAll()
                self.jobs = Job.parseData(snapshot: snapshot)
                //self.tableView.reloadData()
                print(self.jobs)
                //handleComplete()
            }
    }
}
```

I make changes to the document in VC4 and I would like this to be shown in the TableView in VC3 (when the user is popped back).
So I need `jobs` to be updated as FS data is changed.
Everything is working in FS correctly and is updating the server.  Is anyone able to explain how I can do this please?

I have started to create a new Firestore Manager Class...

```
class FSManager {

static let shared = FSManager()
var jobs = [Job]()
var jobCollectionRef: CollectionReference!
var jobListener: ListenerRegistration!

    func loadJobs(completion: @escaping ([Job]) -> Void) {

    self.jobCollectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Job")
    self.jobListener = self.jobCollectionRef
        .whereField("jobUsers", arrayContains: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")
        .addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                debugPrint("Error fetching docs: \(err)")
            } else {

                self.jobs.removeAll()
                self.jobs = Job.parseData(snapshot: snapshot)
                //self.tableView.reloadData()
                print(self.jobs)
                completion(self.jobs)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is then called in VC1.  This appears to be working but I don't understand how I can update the object in VC3.

```
        FSLoadData.shared.loadJobs { jobs in
        self.jobs = jobs
        handleComplete()
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Are all of the view controllers in the same navigation stack where VC1 is directly below VC2, VC2 is directly below VC3, and so forth?

Comment: Yeah all are in same navigation stack.
I'm currently creating the listener in VC1 and segueing over the object from VC1 to VC4.
However, the object isn't being updated.

Comment: You have to make an architectural decision—which object(s) you want to be responsible for managing data and how other objects access it. Perhaps you create a data manager class that VC1 instantiates, that all future objects in the nav stack have a reference to. Perhaps this data manager posts notifications when data updates or view controllers are notified directly through a delegate. You need to think big picture right now and pick an architecture that is simple and extensible. What makes the most sense to you about how these view controllers should share data is what you should choose.

Comment: What occurs in `handleComplete()`?